# Only one web app instance seems to be running

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

We have some timeouts issues with our Azure Web App with 3 instances.
I started debugging using the live stream metrics, and I see something really weird with the CPU usage:

[image]

Can someone explain why only one instance seems to be running?
We suspected the Affinity setting, so we disabled that, no luck.

Restarting that specific instance didn't help neither.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you send requests to each instance to check whether the other 2 instances can be accessed. It will narrow the scope of your issue. For how to send request to a specific Azure Web App instance, link below is for your reference.

[Request for a specific Azure Web App instance](http://blog.amitapple.com/post/2014/03/access-specific-instance/#.WRV0xoVOKtU)

If this issue related to the specific instance, I suggest you scale out your Web App Plan to 1 instance. After it completed, you could scale out your Web App Plan back to 3 instances. It will reassign new instances for your web application.

> and it seems to be struggling to create a socket connection against about Mongo server.

Where and how did you send the requests to your Web App? If the request send from one source, I suggest you turn off the ARR Affinity on Azure portal. After that, Requests from one source will be distribute to all the instances of Web App.

[image]

Comment: it seems that those are not requests coming from the outside world, i run some profiling on this specific instances, and it seems to be struggling to create a socket connection against about Mongo server. Restarting it doesn't seem to help. Do instances run on the same VM? how can we flush the TCP connections for a web app?

Comment: Sorry for late response. I modified my reply based on your comment.